# Rails new objects are nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm playing with rails again and found this behavior, when i create a new instance of a Post model with some attributes it tells me that all attributes are nil, why it is happening?

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.0)
2.0.0-p451 :001 > a = Post.new(title: "Rails", content: "Rails Post")
=> #<Post id: nil, title: nil, content: nil, author: nil, rating: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.0.0-p451 :002 > a.title
=> "Rails"
2.0.0-p451 :004 > a.content
=> "Rails Post" 
2.0.0-p451 :005 > a.inspect
=> "#<Post id: nil, title: nil, content: nil, author: nil, rating: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>"
2.0.0-p451 :006 > a.errors.messages
=> {}
2.0.0-p451 :007 > a.valid?
=> true

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :title, :content, :author, :rating
end
```

Comment: What's in the `development.log` ? How the model looks like ?

Comment: check `a.errors.messages`

Comment: what does your Post model look like?

Comment: there is no development.log since I'm not saving the post object

Answer (score 2):

You are defining `attr_accessor` for all your properties, which is a shortcut for defining getters and setters for an instance variable of the same name like so:

```
def content
  @content
end

def content=(new_content)
  @content = new_content
end
```

Rails will also auto-generate you methods with these names, for every database field that your model has. These methods will conflict with each other.

When you call `post.content = 'foo'`, instead of calling the Rails-generated method that will internally set your model's `content` attribute to 'foo', you're calling the `attr_accessor`-defined method which will set the instance variable `@content` to 'foo'.

The output of `inspect` is iterating over the Rails-defined model attributes, not the instance variables.

Did you actually mean to declare these attributes as `attr_accessible` instead of `attr_accessor`?

Comment: is rails 4, so there isn't attr_accessible any more, the code works fine but the rails console is displaying as if all post attributes were nil but i don't why

Comment: because the model attributes are nil. The instance variables are not, and if you were to save the data to the database, you would also get nils.

Comment: i solved, there was an error in my .irbrc file, i'm working with ruby 2.1.0, but i have to install ruby 2.0.0 for a presentation so rails wasn't finding the gems listed there for ruby 2.1.0